# CSS transform and transition on hover do not work after animation-fill-mode: forwards

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm using a CSS animation to slide a div in when the page loads. (Chrome)

I use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to persist the new state.

From there I would like to have a simple hover animation that uses `transform:scale(2);` and have it transition over 1 second.

My CSS:

```
.box{
  background-color:blue;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation-name: test;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

@keyframes test{
  0% {
     transform: translate(-200px)
  }
  100% {
      transform: translate(0px);
  }
}


.box:hover{
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

[View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/RationalTempest/pen/eZVEPJ)

If I use a simple change on hover, like `border-radius` it works:

```
.box{
  transition: border-radius 0.25s ease;
}

.box:hover{
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Somehow the initial CSS animation is interfering with a transform/transition for the hover state of the element.

If I change the hover to remove the `animation-fill-mode` the `transform` will work, but not the transition:

```
.box:hover{
  animation-fill-mode:none;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Why does transform not work when animation fill mode is forwards?**

As per [W3C pec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-fill-mode-property): (emphasis is mine)

> By default, an animation will not affect property values between the time it is applied (the ‘animation-name’ property is set on an element) and the time it begins execution (which is determined by the ‘animation-delay’ property). Also, by default an animation does not affect property values after the animation ends (determined by the ‘animation-duration’ property). The ‘animation-fill-mode’ property can override this behavior.
>
> If the value for ***‘animation-fill-mode’ is ‘forwards’, then after the animation ends*** (as determined by its ‘animation-iteration-count’), the ***animation will apply the property values for the time the animation ended***.

The above means that the UA has to apply and maintain the `transform` on the element even after the animation has ended. This would sort of imply that the `transform` mentioned within the animation gets precedence and hence the `transform` that is mentioned within the `:hover` state has no effect.

When `animation-fill-mode: none` or `animation-fill-mode: backwards` is applied then the UA does not have to maintain the transformed state after the animation has ended (meaning it kind of becomes like `transform: none`) and so the `transform` within the `:hover` selector works.

This behavior is consistent in latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. In IE11 and Edge the `transform`  that is specified within the `:hover` selector has no effect irrespective of what value is provided for the `animation-fill-mode` property.

---

**Why does transition not work when even when fill mode is changed to none?**

I am not sure if the code in CodePen is the original one or if you made any changes for testing but the `transition` property is wrongly specified in that demo and that is the reason why transition does not happen.

The code that is present is:

```
transition: scale 1s ease;
```

but `scale` is not the ***property*** that needs to be transitioned. It is only the type of transform that needs to be done. The ***property*** is `transform` and hence the code should be as below:

```
transition: transform 1s ease;
```

If you do this change then the `transition` will work if the `animation-fill-mode` is changed.

Comment: Looks like the `transition` was changed, presumably by the original author, but the transition still doesn't happen, at least on Chrome & Firefox. The box just suddenly gets bigger/smaller.